# How to cut a video when there is no human movement in python from fully muted video

Tags: video, motion-detection

I have some store videos which are all muted video. No audio on the videos.

I have tried moviepy, auto-editor but all are they detect audio first. Is there anything which will not detect audio but just work on the human movement. I want to remove the video where there is no human movement on the video.